# Access to all content with specific post type (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I had a question about Wordpress + rest api, 
I use `register_rest_route` for adding new end-point for my collection, and I also created a plugin named as 'article', and the type of this post type also is 'article'.
Now I wanna access all these post types in my new end-point with GET like this :

```
     function my_awesome_func( $post_id ) {
   $x = get_post_type_object( 'article' );
   return $x[$post_id];
 }
 add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'Articles/v2', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
  ) );
} );
```

I know you can't write `$x[$post_id]`. I wrote it to say that I wanna access to specific article id. what should I do?
thanks.

Comment: I also try `get_metadata()`, it doesn't work ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem finally, I post it, it may be useful for others.

```
 add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
          register_rest_route( 'wp/v2/Articles', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
          ) );
        } );
        function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
          $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'article',
            'p'         => $data['id'],
          );
          $query = new WP_Query( $args );

          return $query->post;
        }
```